# Provide dependencies in the implementing app / module

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing a library that I'd like to compile into implementable jar which then will be used in other projects / tests.

In my library I depend on various jars: okHttp, guava, etc., What I want to do is to tell maven not to put those dependencies into the final JAR but make that projects / modules that depend on this library provide those dependencies

How can this be done in maven?

library pom.xml

```xml
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing-library</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>28.2-jre</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

implementation module pom.xml

```xml
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>implementation-</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>testing-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions` error

Comment: basic (configuration): [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html). advanced: [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) (swiss army knife), [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (fat jar!), ... [spring-boot also](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) does its own things.. :)

Comment: ...and `pom/dependency` wise: set the scope to `provided`or `system`!

Comment: if your project is a simple `jar` (the `packaging` tag is either `jar`, or missing), then dependencies (the guava binaries) are not *included* in your jar. They are a transitive dependency of your module, and transitive dependencies are managed  by Maven. Are your clients also maven-based?

Comment: @xerx593, i'm using shade-plugin to generate fat-jar. but that's what I'm trying to avoid. When using provided scope, I end up with 'ClassNotFoundException'.

Comment: @Daniele, yes also maven and yes packaging set to 'jar'.  Regarding transitive dependencies, the issue is that these dependencies are not being resolved by maven and I end up with missing classes during runtime. Although, my library used by test projects, i.e. most of the code in  "/src/test/java". I'm curious whether that's the reason

Comment: Error `NoClassDefFoundError` means that a class required at runtime is not present in the classpath. How exactly are you getting this error- are you running the `testing-library` project, or its test; or are you getting this error from another client who depends on `testing-library`? At any rate- some code needs guava to run, but the guava library is not imported

Comment: also, note that `test` dependencies are **not** transitive. if a client has a a compile dependency on testing-library, guava could be missing. You can check what dependency are imported by calling `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @Daniele, `test` dependencies not being transitive means that `testing-library` `<scope>test</scope> ` dependencies are not visible in the `implementation` project

Comment: not exactly, it means if project B has a test dependency on A, and C has a compile dependency on B, then A won't be a compile dependency on C

Comment: anyway. If you run tests for "implementation", then guava should be included. If you run the "main" configuration of "implementation", then guava will be missing.

Comment: So can you explain what exactly are you running when you get the classNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

If you put code into `src/test/java`, this code will *not* be part of the final jar. The code is meant for tests during the build of the jar.

If your library is a helper library for tests, put the code into `src/main/java` and reference it in other projects with `<scope>test</scope>`.

BTW, don't use Maven shade plugin or Maven assembly plugin for a library. These are mainly meant for standalone jars that run on their own.

Comment: I've updated my question. with pom.xml. Originally I had the same setup you describe but since it wasn't working i opted for shade plugin since i knew that it'd work 100%

Comment: You get the NoClassDefFoundError in the tests of `implementation` or when you run `implementation`.

Comment: When running the tests of `implementation`

Comment: Your configuration looks right and you should see guava. Can you look at the `dependency:tree` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the issue. It seems that the generated POM.xml for the `testing-library` did not contain any dependencies.

I was using `mvn install:install-file ... -DgeneratePom=true` for installing jar into local repository for quick debugging and the pom generated this way seemed to be lacking library dependencies'

Comment: Ok ... that it explains it. Why not just run `mvn clean install`?